# "Barrier functions" in function spaces

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, linear-programming, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

In general the idea of a "barrier function" (as in the context of "interior point methods") can possibly be thought of as defining a function corresponding to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ such that its continuous in the interior but goes singular on its closure.

Are there examples of being able to define such barrier functions on some (full-measure) subset of some infinite dimensional function space? Is there any analogue of barrier function that is known in the context of functional analysis?

Comment: As long as your feasible set is described in the form $\{ x \in X \colon g(x) \leq 0\}$ for a reasonably regular real-valued function $g$, what is keeping you from following the standard approaches with e.g. a logarithmic barrier function? -- Anyway, you are not the first one to think of this as e.g. a google search reveals. There is also a treatment of barrier functions in Banach spaces analogous to the one of Nesterov/Nemirovski in the [dissertation of Florian Kruse](https://mediatum.ub.tum.de/doc/1182603/1182603.pdf).

Comment: I am thinking of a situation whereby the subset of the function space is known to me as a finitely parameterized set of functions. (so this set is infinite dimensional) Then I dont have a functional like $g$ which would evaluate to a non-negative number on this subset. Now is there a way to define a barrier function on this set of functions?

Comment: I fear this will depend on the actual description of your desired feasible set. (As a sidenote, I do not quite understand your insistence on the infinite dimensions of the feasible set, a set of the form $[g \leq 0]$ as mentioned in my first comment may very well be full-dimensional?)